# Hadoop job cannot see the file, that hadoop fs -cat prints just fine

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I have some code that accesses a file on hdfs in a function that is called from main() before launching the job.

This is a single node cluster (pseudo distributed mode) on a mac.

I am not sure if this is an issue due to me calling the function before I launch a job, but I am getting the following errors:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: hdfs:/localhost/usr/local/tmp/hadoop/hadoop-${user}/data/input/file.csv (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at org.apache.mahout.common.iterator.FileLineIterator.getFileInputStream(FileLineIterator.java:116)
    at org.apache.mahout.common.iterator.FileLineIterable.<init>(FileLineIterable.java:53)
    at org.apache.mahout.common.iterator.FileLineIterable.<init>(FileLineIterable.java:48)
    at profile2sparse.MRDriver.createDictionaryChunks(MRDriver.java:98)
    at profile2sparse.MRDriver.main(MRDriver.java:177)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
```

I can see the contents of this file with hadoop fs -cat

Thanks and Regards,
Atul.

Comment: Please ignore the hdfs:/localhost/usr/... part, it gives the same result if I give hdfs://localhost:8020/... or /usr/local/tmp/...

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to cat the file with below command?
hadoop fs -cat hdfs:/localhost/usr/local/tmp/hadoop/hadoop-${USER}/data/input/file.csv

If yes, it looks like ${user} is not resolved in your program.  Make sure to uppercase ${user} like ${USER}.